# regular expression for a folder name that never contain / at the start or end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field for folder name and i want to check wither input contain `/` at the start or at the end.

```
foldername/  wrong
/foldername  wrong
foldername   correct
mainfolder/subfolder correct
```

Comment: `/` can be in between right? `foldername/somethin` ?????///

Answer (score 1):

```
^\w+(/\w+)*$
```

This should do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/42

Comment: @user3262732 try `^\w+([/]\w+)*$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex.

```
^(?!/|.*/$).+$
```

Comment: It does work. You need to escape those characters and use `test` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/r350ck2t/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^\/][\s\S]+[^\/]$/.test('/aa') // false  
/^[^\/][\s\S]+[^\/]$/.test('aa/') // false  
/^[^\/][\s\S]+[^\/]$/.test('/a/') // false  
/^[^\/][\s\S]+[^\/]$/.test('aaa') // true  
/^[^\/][\s\S]+[^\/]$/.test('a/a') // true
```